# How to exclude class name from the name of the inherited test in NUnit

Tags: .net, testing, inheritance, nunit

I have a base class with testcases(methods).  Also I have another class inherited from base class with some overloaded test cases(methods).
The issue is that names of inherited testcases(in interpretation of NUnit) contain the name of the base class. Is there an ability to exclude base class name from the name of the inherited test cases and make it look the same as overloaded one.

For example:

inherited method in childClass:

```
Namespace.parentClass.childClass.name
```

overloaded method in childClass:

```
Namespace.childClass.name
```

Comment: Do you really need testmethods on different levels of inheritance?

Comment: It's more expensive, but you could use the `Description` attribute to describe your test. This should also work with inherited methods.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the "test case" attribute from the test cases in the base class, and add test case methods to the child class that just call the methods in the base class. Ie the child class explicitly declares the tests itself, but defers implementation to the base class.